# awk oneliner provide this error "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,"

Tags: bash, awk

Can someone tell me why this simple awk command gives the above error

`echo "24_02_2022.rar" | awk '{match($0,/.+_(.+).rar/,a); print a[1]}'`

I would like to extract the year from a string

Comment: Your version of `awk` probably doesn't support the three-argument version of `match`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the gnu [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function) function with the array argument:

> The array argument to match() is a gawk extension.

One option with `awk` could be setting the field separators to `.` and `_` and then match the last underscore followed by `.rar` at the end of the string.

Then print the second to last field.

```
echo "24_02_2022.rar" | awk -F"[._]" '/_[^_]*\.rar$/ {print $(NF-1)}'
```

Output

```
2022
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple `echo "24_02_2022.rar" | awk -F "[_.]" '{print $3}'` ?

**Output:**

`2022`

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash solution, assuming the bash version used is greater than or equal to 4.2, could be

```
IFS=._ read -ra a <<< "24_02_2022.rar"
echo "${a[-2]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed you need to use GNU `AWK`, firstly try

```
echo "24_02_2022.rar" | gawk '{match($0,/.+_(.+).rar/,a); print a[1]}'
```

if that does not work and you get complaint that gawk is not present try installing (if you are using popular distro there is good chance it is available in default packaging manager of your system), if you are not allowed to install your solution might be ported to GNU `sed` following way

```
echo "24_02_2022.rar" | sed 's/.*_\(..*\).rar.*/\1/'
```

However keep in mind that all dotes match any character including that before `rar`, if this is not what you want then use

```
echo "24_02_2022.rar" | sed 's/.*_\(..*\)[.]rar.*/\1/'
```

Observe that in comparison to regular expression used in GNU `AWK` I added trailing `.*` to remove following characters if any.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, probably the simplest way is

```
basename '24_02_2022.rar' .rar
```

that returns

```
24_02_2022
```

Comment: The OP wants to extract the year (2022).

Answer (score 0):

absolutely no need to rely on that 3rd argument for `match()`:

```
echo "24_02_2022.rar" |
```

> ```
> gawk -F'_' '{ print substr($NF,++_,-_+index($NF,".")) }' # too verbose
> ```

—  or

> ```
> nawk 'NF+=OFS=_' FS='^.+_|.rar'
> mawk NF=NF OFS= FS='^.+_|.rar'  # shorter by tiny bit
> ```

—  or

> ```
> mawk 'gsub("^.+_|.rar",_)^_'    # most succinct
> ```

```
2022
```

If you wanna gamble there aren't empty lines, then :

> ```
> mawk -F'[_.]' '$!NF=$--NF' FS=
> gawk -F'[_.]' '$_=$--NF'
> ```

or a ***VERY*** fringe way of doing it :

> ```
> nawk NF RS='.+_|[.].+'
> ```

```
2022
```